# Find max date in list of dates in Java

Tags: java

I have multiple dates as below:

```
11/12/2020
12/10/2020,
2/19/2021,
3/16/2021,
3/18/2021,
1/19/2021
```

How can I find the max date using Java?

Comment: How are the dates represented? `String`? `Date`? `LocalDate`? `LocalDateTime`? `ZonedDateTime`? `Instant`? ...

Comment: Dates are represented in String.

Comment: Single elements of list are in String form.

Comment: Then: convert the `String`s in (preferrably) `LocalDate`s through a `DateTimeFormatter`, iterate over the `LocalDate`s, compare them, store the maximum.

Comment: Date maxDate = list.stream().max((x, y) -> x.compareTo(y));

Comment: Why is this Question closed for "details or clarity"? What is unclear about wanting the latest date from a list of strings?

Comment: Perhaps because important information was put into comments rather than the question?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
List.of( "11/12/2020" , "12/10/2020" , "2/19/2021" , "3/16/2021" , "3/18/2021" , "1/19/2021" )
        .stream()
        .map( s -> LocalDate.parse( s , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" ) ) )
        .max( LocalDate :: compareTo )
        .get()
        .toString()
```

> 2021-03-18

## *java.time*

Parse your string inputs as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects, a class found in the *java.time* package.

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs. Tip: Learn to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values textually.

From a stream of these `LocalDate` objects, find the latest, the maximum value.

Streams return an object as an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) to avoid the problems involved with possibly returning null values. So call `get` the extract the embedded `LocalDate` object (assuming you know for sure the `Optional` is not empty).

```java
List < String > inputs = List.of( "11/12/2020" , "12/10/2020" , "2/19/2021" , "3/16/2021" , "3/18/2021" , "1/19/2021" );

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" );  // Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.
LocalDate latest = 
    inputs
    .stream()                               // Create a stream of objects emanating from the list.
    .map( s -> LocalDate.parse( s , f ) )   // Parse each input string into a `LocalDate` object, thereby altering our stream to a stream of `LocalDate` objects rather than `String` objects.
    .max( LocalDate :: compareTo )          // Find the largest of these objects, the latest `LocalDate` object. 
    .get()                                  // Extract the latest `LocalDate` object from its `Optional` wrapper. This call assumes you know for certain that the `Optional` is not empty.
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/tBFtF2).

> inputs = [11/12/2020, 12/10/2020, 2/19/2021, 3/16/2021, 3/18/2021, 1/19/2021]
>
> latest = 2021-03-18

Answer (score 0):

If performance are not too important to you, I think the best and simplest implementation
would be to convert into a date format and then compare the dates.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
dateTime.isAfter(otherDate);
```

Comment: Incorrect pattern. The inputs shown in the Question have no padding zeros on single-digit values.

Comment: Its not a copy paste solution, OP has a brain he can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort()` does the trick:

```java
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
Date date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2020, 4, 1).getTime();
Date date2 = new GregorianCalendar(2019, 4, 1).getTime();
Date date3 = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 4, 1).getTime();
dates.add(date1);
dates.add(date2);
dates.add(date3);
Collections.sort(dates);
Date lastDate = dates.get(dates.size()-1);
```

Result:

```
Fri May 01 00:00:00 UTC 2020
```

Works with dates in String form too:

```java
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add("11/12/2020");
dates.add("12/10/2020");
dates.add("2/19/2021");
dates.add("3/16/2021");
dates.add("3/18/2021");
dates.add("1/19/2021");
Collections.sort(dates);
System.out.println(dates.get(dates.size()-1));
```

Result:

```
3/18/2021
```

Comment: Jumping through unnecessary hoops. The `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, & `GregorianCalendar` classes are terrible. They were replaced years ago by the much more sensible *java.time* classes, specifically `Instant`, `LocalDate`, and `ZonedDateTime` respectively.

Comment: Unless required by OP, please avoid posting answers revolving around legacy classes like `Date`. Instead, prefer teaching modern solutions.

Comment: @chandansah If my answer answers the question, please consider accepting :)